# C++: Why are arrays on the stack allocated after "normal" ints for instance, regardless of ordering in the code?

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++

Performing some tests on how c++ compilers (in my case g++ on linux) behave when allocating local variables on the stack.
Take a look at this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int prev = 10;
    int myArr[5] = {4, 5, 7, 2, 1};
    int next = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

All of these variables are allocated on the stack.
One would think that that segment of the stack looks like this:

prev myArr next

But when inspecting the stack with gdb, it looks like this:

```
0x7fffffffd640: 0xf7dd1fc8      0x00007fff      0x0000000a      0x0000000a
0x7fffffffd650: 0x00000004      0x00000005      0x00000007      0x00000002
0x7fffffffd660: 0x00000001      0x00007fff      0x2cf9f100      0x09108235
```

As you can see from the 0x0000000a values, both int variables are allocated before the array.
Why is this the case? Some kind of optimization putting the larger int-array after the smaller 4byte ints or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: Your guess it has to do with size, my guess is that the compiler used reverse alphabetical order for the names. Or maybe the  hash values from the symbol table. The standard doesn't say what method to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One would think that that segment of the stack looks like this:
>
> prev myArr next

This order is not guaranteed.

> Some kind of optimization putting the larger int-array after the smaller 4byte ints or am i missing something?

Yes, the compiler may arrange the objects as it likes. Order of objects on the stack is not specified and may differ.

---

A variable may not even be allocated on the stack at all when the compiler sees that it isnt necessary. For example this:

```
 int main() {
     int x = 42;
     return x;
 }
```

is equivalent to

```
 int main() {
     return 42;
 }
```

When optimizations are turned on the compiler should notice that and make use of the as-if-rule to produce optimized output.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so it's an optimization.

Comment: @pixx i dont know if this particular order you observe has an advantage. The point is that it is wrong to assume that they are allocated in the order you declare them in your code, any order would be in accordance with the C++ standard

Comment: @pixx I guess you are looking at a debug build. I wouldnt be surprised if the order is different when optimizations are turned on